# Cannot call this faker function on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, faker

I have followed tutorial on how to mask attributes using the faker python library. Here is my code below:

```
def anonymize_rows(rows):
    faker = Factory.create

    first_name = defaultdict(faker.first_name)
    last_name = defaultdict(faker.last_name)

    for row in rows:
        row['FirstName'] = names[row['first_name']]
        row['LastName'] = names[row['last_name']]

        yield row

#def anonymize (source,target):

    with open('MasterSubscriberDE20170421.csv', 'rU') as f:
        with open('Master1.csv', 'w') as o:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)

            for row in anonymize_rows(reader):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

When I try to execute it by calling

```
anonymize_rows('MastersusbscriberDE20170421.csv') # File I want to mask
```

I get :
**generator object anonymize_rows at 0x12353fdb0**

What am I doing wrong? I am using Python 3.5 with the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `yield` is returning an iterable. You'll need to iterate over it and use the results.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Can you please expand on this? I do not understand how to iterate over it.

Comment: result = anonymize_rows('filename')
for item in result:
   print item


Try this

Comment: Tried this and got an error will update my question with the error

Comment: Can you share an ideone link of the code?

Comment: Here it is @GauravOjha https://ideone.com/5i8OjV.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with this - http://ideone.com/DbtRY4
other than the indentation.

Comment: Is it the indentation on the with?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Check my code and see if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142506/discussion-between-gaurav-ojha-and-data-kid).